# How can I find out what's causing my Oracle transaction to hang with a wait class of Cluster?

Tags: oracle, cluster-computing, wait

I have an Oracle procedure that is run several hundred times a day. Maybe once every few days, the session hangs with a wait class of Cluster. I've seen it hang for a couple of hours, and I always have to have it terminated.

I've seen info Cluster waits causing performance issues, but not anything about them causing indefinite hangs. I'm trying to find out any queries I can run to find out what's causing the wait the next time one pops up, or any pointers for likely culprits that might be causing this.

Comment: So the query is probably trying to pull current data blocks from other cluster nodes (possibly to build a temporary result set for a join or sort?) and either those blocks are unavailable for some reason (locked) or possibly there just isn't enough throughput in your RAC interconnect to pull everything over fast enough. Check your ADDM or AWR reports for the period in question to see what they show is happening in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to investigate waits is to look at the Active Session History views, such as `GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` and `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY`. Whatever tool you're using to look at the database performance is likely already a summary of the data in those views, so for advanced troubleshooting you need to dig into them yourself.

The `GV$` view contains data in memory, usually only a few hours worth, and the `DBA_HIST` view usually contains days of data. Use the `GV$` view if possible because the `DBA_HIST` views can be slow if there's a ton of historical data.

I can't tell you exactly what columns to look for - you're just looking for something "weird". But from my experience, the below columns are your best bet for troubleshooting a specific wait problem:

1. **INST_ID and SESSION_ID** - Identify which session.
2. **SQL_ID** - Even though you're running a procedure, most likely the problem is coming from one SQL statement inside it. If there's a problem with the statement you'll want to look at the execution plan, which is a whole other type of troubleshooting.
3. **EVENT** - This will tell you what kind of cluster wait it is.
4. **P1TEXT/P1, P2TEXT/P2, P3TEXT/P3** - These values change depending on the wait event. For example, if P1TEXT is "file#", then P1 will be a number that corresponds to DBA_DATA_FILES.FILE_ID. If you have a "hot block", some part of your disk or SAN that is overused and performing poorly, it may show up here.
5. **CURRENT_OBJ#** - Join to DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_ID to find out which object is being waited on.

(And make sure you're using an IDE instead of the command line. Viewing this much data in SQL*Plus is almost impossible.)